# Is Horizon semi-centralized?

Tags: horizon

While anyone can host a Horizon server, is this considered a semi-centralized entry point because the primary REST endpoint for most clients will be through Stellar's own horizon.stellar.com?

Are there other known public stellar hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. No.

It is definitely a potential single-point-of-failure at the moment, but as we progress, more will come online and more apps will start supporting other servers.

Ideally, if you're running a service on top of the network, you would run your own Horizon server too, just as you should run your own stellar-core.
Remember, that's the only way *you* get to pick what other validators to trust.